# Developer Tools in Chrome Canary not displaying properly

Tags: google-chrome

When I bring up the dev tools in Chrome Canary, it just appears as a black box. I have it set to display in another window rather than overlaying the actual page, but as said, the inside of this window is just black. If I hover the mouse over it, it highlights the elements on the page accordingly.

I have tried: Looking for settings to dock it back into the screen, restarting CC, restarting my computer, reverting to default settings in the CC menu. None of this has changed a thing unfortunately.

EDIT: Has been resolved with update to version 33.0.1707.0

Comment: I can confirm this defect. I have the same problem.

Comment: Yep! I have the same problem too.
( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903615/google-chrome-extension-in-dev-mode-stopped-working-properly ), (  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=317996 )

Comment: Also -> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=317445&q=canary%20black%20dev%20tools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: This morning's build fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same thing happened to me, starting sometime in the past two days.  I tried everything you did and also tried reinstalling Chrome Canary, no dice.  My solution was to dock the developer tools back to the main browser window by clicking in the upper-right corner of the black box, where I think the dock icon usually is.

Comment: Ah nice one, can confirm this works if you don't mind having the developer tools docked in the main window (if you try and unlocking it back into a separate window, it goes black again).

Seems to be a fairly recent problem which no doubt will be fixed soon, I'll mark this as the answer as it's enabled me to at least see it again :)

Comment: This has been fixed in version 33.0.1707.0 canary -> see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=317445&q=canary%20black%20dev%20tools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified